# Emulator: Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Tags: android

I recently just started downloaded Android Studio Version 3.0.1 on a Mac and I'm getting the error below:

> Emulator: Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

I followed the Android Studio tutorial and was able to run the emulator but after adding in a text box and a button, the error above popped up. Please help!

Comment: faced the same error, I just created new Emulator & its working fine.

Comment: facing same error, did you get any solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I faced the same problem and I don't know exactly why this might happen on the system. But I noticed that this problem only occur whenever I want to execute the emulator after it has been closed and its state has been saved. As a workaround you can do the following:

- Open AVD Manager in your Android Studio
- For the desired emulator, from the list click on the down arrow located on the right side of its row
- Select "Cold Boot Now"

Doing so, you are able to change your program and execute it provided that you haven't closed your emulator. Whenever you close it, you need to do the above instructions again.

Comment: Does it also help to set "Cold boot" as the default for the Virtual Device (Click pencil icon for emulator > Click "Show Advanced Settings" > Scroll to "Emulated Performance" > choose Boot option: "Cold boot")

Answer (score 7):

I solved it by going into my virtual device's settings and changing "Emulated Performance" from "Automatic" to "Software".

Comment: seems to be the right answer. The problem seems to be particularly common among linux machines.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

open Virtual Device, select Device and Edit -
Change Camera Front from Emulated to be None -
Change Camera Back from VirtualScene to be None -
Change Quick boot to be Cold boot -
Change Multi-Core CPU  4 to be 2