# I am trying to use Webcam on the emulator but got 'interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT error' on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera

I am trying to use my webcam of laptop on the emulator because I don't really need to carry devices and USBs while I develop some apps using cams.

And I found out that there's an option. So, I what I did was

1. open AVD Manager
2. select the emulator.
3. Show Advanced Setting and set like this.

[image]

4. Build the project & Install it & Start the emulator.

But I got: [signal 6: SIGABRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217137/emulator-process-finished-with-exit-code-134-interrupted-by-signal-6-sigabrt) error

So, I tried with different settings like Hardware GLES 2.0, Software GLES 2.0, Cold boot, Quick boot. But still get the same error and the emulator closes.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: same situation, any idea?

Comment: @hksfho I haven't solved it yet..