# Emulator Path on Android Studio for Mac

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-emulator

I upgraded my emulators in Android Studio Hedgehog (Catalina) and my Emulators crash. The error message is:

`2023-12-20 21:01:37,234 [  47251]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6a API 34 - Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT) 2023-12-20 21:01:37,238 [  47255] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6a API 34 - Emulator terminated with exit code 134`

When I query the Emulators location, I get the path: `/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator`, but the Emulators are really at the path: `/Library/Application Support/Android/SDK/tools`.

I theorize that if I could add the "Application Support" level to the path, it might solve the problem, but I'm not sure how I could do that.

Additionally, I also theorize that not having the Intel HAXM installed could be the problem. Thing is, it doesn't show up as an upgrade option in Android Studio Hedgehog.

If that's not the problem, I'd love to hear your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround for a similar problem from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48793752/12282360).

- Open AVD Manager in your Android Studio
- For the desired emulator, from the list click on the down arrow located on the right side of its row
- Select "Cold Boot Now"

Additionally, try going into your virtual device's settings and change "Emulated Performance" from "Automatic" to "Software" as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50471149/12282360) suggests.

Comment: Thanks.
You know I read those posts and tried Cold Boot a number of times.
For some reason the Emulated Performance is Greyed out and I haven't been able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried a lot of suggestions, but the simple solution was to downgrade my Emulators.
A great HOW TO is at https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive. It includes the Android archives of Emulators.

When in doubt go back further in the Emulator history.

Comment: Try to write in third person.